# Tag boundary vertices after 3d triangulation

Tags: 3d, cgal

My goal is to tag all the vertices of a 3d regular-triangulated mesh as inner or outer vertices.
I'm aware of the infinite vertex.

I iterate through all the adjacent vertices of the infinite vertex and tag them as outer vertices.
When do that i get strange results:

right pic: all the vertices of the mushroom.
middle pic: vertices tagged as outer.
left pic: vertices tagged as inner

http://i62.tinypic.com/2uqj6hj.jpg

when I do the same thing but with a sphere mesh i get correct results.
Am I not understanding the infinite vertex correctly?
How can i solve this?

P.S. I'm new to cgal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this finally by using sub-domains

```
for (C3t3::Facets_in_complex_iterator
    fit = i_pTetrahedlizedMesh.facets_in_complex_begin(),
    end = i_pTetrahedlizedMesh.facets_in_complex_end();
fit != end; ++fit)
{
    C3t3::Subdomain_index cell_sd = i_pTetrahedlizedMesh.subdomain_index(fit->first);
    C3t3::Subdomain_index opp_sd = i_pTetrahedlizedMesh.subdomain_index(fit->first->neighbor(fit->second));

    if (cell_sd != 0 && opp_sd != 0) continue; //this is an inner vertex
    else .... //this is an outer vertex
```

Answer (score 0):

In CGAL triangulations, the vertices that are adjacent to the infinite vertex are exactly those that are on the convex hull of the set of points.

If you want to reconstruct a shape, like your mushroom, you will need to use reconstruction algorithms. The simplest in CGAL one is the [3D Alpha Shapes](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/index.html), but you may want to use 
[Surface Reconstruction from Point Sets](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/index.html).